# Recursive function too slow for creating hierarchical lists

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

I have a Pandas DataFrame with two columns [Key, Parent]

```
key_x         parent_x1
parent_x1     parent_x2
key_y         parent_y1
parent_x2     parent_x3
key_z         parent_z1
parent_z4     parent_z5
parent_x3     parent_x4
parent_x4     parent_x5
parent_x5     parent_x5  #last parent (same keys)
...
```

and I want to rebuild, from the Dataframe, the hierarchical list for each "leaf" entry this way:

```
[key_x1, parent_x2, parent_x3, parent_x4, parent_x5]
[key_y1, parent_y2, parent_y3, parent_y4, parent_y5]
[key_z1, parent_z2, parent_z3, parent_z4, parent_z5]
....
```

I tried this recursive function:

```
def _get_parent(df, val, tree=[]):
    #this is the last parent: return the final tree
    if  (val not in df.index) or (val == df.loc[val,"Parent"]): 
        return tree
    #save the current entry and get the next parent recurively
    tree.append(val)
    return _get_parent(df, df.loc[val,"Parent"],tree)
```

Which I use this way for the dataframe this way:

```
keys= []
for index, _ in df.iterrows():
    # if it does not appear as a parent, get all its parents
    if index not in df.Parent.values: 
        keys.append(_get_parent(df,index,[]))

print(Keys)
```

This code works fine but it seems extremely slow, it takes about 3 minutes for a 100k Dataframe for example. (regular CPU/Memory)

I'm looking for a way to speed it up